# Query for empty has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

How can I query a `has_many :through` to see which records have an empty association on the other side? (I'm using rails 5)

```
class Specialty
  has_many :doctor_specialties
  has_many :doctor_profiles, through: :doctor_specialties

class DoctorProfile
  has_many :doctor_specialties
  has_many :specialties, through: :doctor_specialties

class DoctorSpecialty
  belongs_to :doctor_profile
  belongs_to :specialty
```

I can do this by enumerating over `Specialty` but I'd like to do it in a SQL query.

```
Specialty.includes(:doctor_profiles).all.select{|x| x.doctor_profiles.length == 0 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Specialty.includes(:doctor_profiles).where(doctor_profiles: { id: nil })
```

See [Active Record Query Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) for more info on AR querying.

Since you're on Rails >= 5, you could use [`left_outer_joins`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#left-outer-joins) (thx **@gmcnaughton**):

```
Specialty.left_outer_joins(:doctor_profiles).where(doctor_profiles: { id: nil })
```

Comment: Starting with Rails 5 you can use `left_outer_joins` instead of `includes` - see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#left-outer-joins

Answer (score 1):

You can also achieve this using following query.

```
Specialty.where.not(id: DoctorSpecialty.select(:speciality_id))
```

Above statement will create a query inside query. No need for table joins.

Answer (score 0):

```
Speciality.joins('left join doctor_profiles on doctor_profiles.speciality_id = specialities.id').where(doctor_profiles: {id: nil})
```